# Is there a way to run a function on something after it is written (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, lambda

I am creating a `tkinter` app with python, and I am faced with a problem.

```
from   tkinter import *
import math

root = Tk()
root.title("PyCalc")
root.resizable(False, False)

inpbox = Entry(root, width=40, borderwidth=5, font=("Courier New", 16))
inpbox.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=5, padx=0, pady=10)


def clicked(num):
    inpbox.focus()
    if num == 'C': inpbox.delete(0, END)
    elif num == '=':
        inpbox.icursor(END)
        text = inpbox.get().replace('√', "math.sqrt").replace('^', '**')
        inpbox.delete(0, END)
        try: num = eval(text)
        except: inpbox.insert(END, '?')
        else:
            try: inpbox.insert(inpbox.index(INSERT), float(num))
            except: inpbox.insert(END, '?')
    elif num == 'B':
        inpbox.delete(inpbox.index(INSERT)-1, inpbox.index(INSERT))
    else: inpbox.insert(inpbox.index(INSERT), num)


inpbox.focus()
button00 = Button(root, text='00', padx=17, pady=20, font=("Courier New", 32), command=lambda: clicked('00'))
button0 = Button(root, text='0', padx=30, pady=20, font=("Courier New", 32), command=lambda: clicked('0'))
button1 = Button(root, text='1', padx=30, pady=20, font=("Courier New", 32), command=lambda: clicked('1'))
button2 = Button(root, text='2', padx=30, pady=20, font=("Courier New", 32), command=lambda: clicked('2'))
button3 = Button(root, text='3', padx=30, pady=20, font=("Courier New", 32), command=lambda: clicked('3'))
button4 = Button(root, text='4', padx=30, pady=20, font=("Courier New", 32), command=lambda: clicked('4'))
button5 = Button(root, text='5', padx=30, pady=20, font=("Courier New", 32), command=lambda: clicked('5'))
button6 = Button(root, text='6', padx=30, pady=20, font=("Courier New", 32), command=lambda: clicked('6'))
button7 = Button(root, text='7', padx=30, pady=20, font=("Courier New", 32), command=lambda: clicked('7'))
button8 = Button(root, text='8', padx=30, pady=20, font=("Courier New", 32), command=lambda: clicked('8'))
button9 = Button(root, text='9', padx=30, pady=20, font=("Courier New", 32), command=lambda: clicked('9'))
buttonplus = Button(root, text='+', padx=30, pady=20, font=("Courier New", 32), command=lambda: clicked('+'))
buttonsub = Button(root, text='-', padx=30, pady=20, font=("Courier New", 32), command=lambda: clicked('-'))
buttonmult = Button(root, text='*', padx=30, pady=20, font=("Courier New", 32), command=lambda: clicked('*'))
buttondiv = Button(root, text='/', padx=30, pady=20, font=("Courier New", 32), command=lambda: clicked('/'))
buttonsqr = Button(root, text='√', padx=30, pady=20, font=("Courier New", 32), command=lambda: clicked('√('))
buttonsq = Button(root, text='x²', padx=17, pady=20, font=("Courier New", 32), command=lambda: clicked('^2'))
buttonpow = Button(root, text='xⁿ', padx=17, pady=20, font=("Courier New", 32), command=lambda: clicked('^'))
buttoneq = Button(root, text='=', padx=91, pady=20, font=("Courier New", 32), command=lambda: clicked('='))
buttonc = Button(root, text='C', padx=30, pady=20, font=("Courier New", 32), command=lambda: clicked('C'))
buttonb = Button(root, text='Õ', padx=11, pady=20, font=("Wingdings", 31), command=lambda: clicked('B'))
buttonfact = Button(root, text='x!', padx=17, pady=20, font=("Courier New", 32), command=lambda: clicked('!'))
buttonlp = Button(root, text='(', padx=30, pady=20, font=("Courier New", 32), command=lambda: clicked('('))
buttonrp = Button(root, text=')', padx=30, pady=20, font=("Courier New", 32), command=lambda: clicked(')'))

buttonsq.grid(row=1, column=4)
buttonplus.grid(row=1, column=3)
button9.grid(row=1, column=2)
button8.grid(row=1, column=1)
button7.grid(row=1, column=0)

buttonpow.grid(row=2, column=4)
buttonsub.grid(row=2, column=3)
button6.grid(row=2, column=2)
button5.grid(row=2, column=1)
button4.grid(row=2, column=0)

buttonsqr.grid(row=3, column=4)
buttonmult.grid(row=3, column=3)
button3.grid(row=3, column=2)
button2.grid(row=3, column=1)
button1.grid(row=3, column=0)

buttonfact.grid(row=4, column=4)
buttondiv.grid(row=4, column=3)
buttonb.grid(row=4, column=2)
button00.grid(row=4, column=1)
button0.grid(row=4, column=0)

buttonc.grid(row=5, column=4)
buttoneq.grid(row=5, column=2, columnspan=2)
buttonrp.grid(row=5, column=1)
buttonlp.grid(row=5, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

When the exclamation mark is clicked a `!` is shown. But it has no effect on the equation and results in an error (which leaves a question mark on the screen)

For aesthetic purposes I want to avoid adding a `!(` to the equation or a `fact(`; it would take too much space, and it's not the way you .

In theory, if I entered `3!` the program would output `6`.

I have tried:

- Doing `setattr(int, 'factorial', fact)` where `fact` is `def fact(self): return math.factorial(self)` (math had been imported in the program already) just returns the error:

```
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    setattr(int, 'factorial', fact)
TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'int'
```

I had hoped that I could add to the `.replace` chain in the third row of the `clicked()` function: `text = inpbox.get().replace('√', "math.sqrt").replace('^', '**').replace('!', '.factorial()')`, but since python won't let me add that attribute to numbers it was fruitless.

- trying `int.__setattr__()` yielded around the same results.

Comment: Why don't you do it the same way as you do `math.sqrt()`?

Comment: How can you do that @Barmar? If I try and do the conversion with `3!` it would turn into `3math.factorial(`

Comment: You need to do more proper parsing. Change it to `math.factorial(3)`

Comment: @Barmar could you show an example on how to turn `3!` into `math.factorial(3)`

Comment: `text = re.sub(r'\d+$', r'math.factorial(\0)', inpbox.get())`

Comment: ...btw, "proper parsing" is typically a 300-level course in any typical computer science university program -- twenty years ago, the class was called compiler design, and [the "dragon book"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools) was the most widely-used text on the topic. There are lots of proper parser generators for Python; https://wiki.python.org/moin/LanguageParsing has a list.

Comment: (anything of that sort is vastly overkill if factorials are the _only_ thing you need, but if you want to support arbitrary syntax, it's the path to go down; `str.replace()` is not going to get you all that far).

Comment: @Barmar when I run your code it tells me that `'re' is not defined`. Do I need to import anything?

Comment: Of course, you need to import the `re` module.

Comment: P.S. I imported `re`, but it still doesn't work! I tried to test it with `print(text = re.sub(r'\d+$', r'math.factorial(\0)', '3!')` but it just returned '3!'

Comment: @Barmar ????????

Comment: I didn't realize the string had `!` in it. So the pattern should be `r'\d+!'`

Comment: `re.sub(r'(\d+)!', r'math.factorial(\g<0>)', '3!')`

Comment: but @Barmar can this work for something like 3! + 4!? Or should I go with Charles Duffy's suggestion....

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: If you want something that works for all combinations of operators, you need to write a real parser.

Comment: @Barmar yes I did...